# jQuery empty "or" selector?

Tags: jquery, selector, tableofcontents

Is there a jQuery selector that will get the content of an element's attribute, but if the attribute is empty, it will get the content of the element itself?  For example, say I have the following HTML:

```
<h2 alt="apple">Hello, world</h1>
<h2>banana</h2>
```

Essentially, I want it to do something like "h2.alt|h2" (so, if no "alt" tag, select the element itself).

In this example, I want to be able to get the following in a list:

```
apple
banana
```

The reason for this is that I will be using a jQuery ToC plugin that allows you to give it jQuery selectors for which elements to pull the ToC from (e.g. "h1,h2,h3").  I want to be able to specify in some of my  elements an alternate attribute if I want the ToC text to be different from the content/header text.

Any help would  be great!

Thanks!

EDIT:

Just to clarify - it would have to be a *selector*, because it's something that I have to pass into the plugin.  (Such as "h2.alt,h3,h4.alt|h4").  It can't be actual code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/U8T2b/)**

```
$('h2').each(function (id, value) {
    var altAttr = $(this).attr('alt');
    if (altAttr === undefined) alert($(this).text());
    else alert(altAttr);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I edited my question for clarification.  Basically need a selector, if one exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
var results = $('h2').map(function(){
    var $this = $(this), alt = $this.attr('alt')
    return alt  == undefined ? $(this).text() : alt 
}).get();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YT6tH/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.  I edited my question for clarification.  Basically need a selector, if one exists.

Comment: it can't be a selector, because you are not using it to filter elements, you are trying to fetch the value using this property